# Getting multiple versions of Ubuntu working on separate SSDs

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation

I have a laptop with two 500 GB internal SSDs that uses a dual boot setup, with Windows 10 installed on the first internal SSD and Ubuntu 18.04 installed on the second internal SSD, which has been working great so far.

I also have a 1 TB external SSD, and have been trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on that. However, if I do install Ubuntu 16.04 on the external 1 TB SSD, it breaks the Ubuntu 18.04 installation on my 500 GB internal SSD (that is, I have to use the `boot repair` tool to fix GRUB). Furthermore, I’m also unable to actually boot into Ubuntu 16.04 on the 1 TB external SSD I just installed it on, which has left me scratching my head. This is the installation process I followed to try and install Ubuntu 16.04 on my 1 TB external SSD:

1)  Using a bootable USB, I choose the `Try Ubuntu without installing` option.

2)  Once Ubuntu has booted from the USB, I start the installer called `Install Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS`

3)  After getting to the 4th menu, I choose the `Something else` installation type option

4)  I see that the 1 TB external SSD is under `/dev/sdb`, so I create a `swap area` as the first partition (`/dev/sdb1`) and an `Ext4 journaling file system` as the second partition (`/dev/sdb2`) with `Mount point` set to `/`

5)  In the `Device for boot loader installation` dropdown box, I choose the 1 TB external SSD

6)  With his done, I click on `Install Now`, which completes successfully

However, when I then restart my computer, I’m unable to choose the 1 TB external SSD as a bootable drive, and if I try and boot back into Ubuntu 18.04 that was installed on one of my internal 500 GB SSDs, I get a GRUB error which requires me to use `boot repair` to fix it (thankfully Windows 10 didn’t explode like the 2 Ubuntu versions did).

Right now I’m at a loss for what to do next, as I’ve spent the entire day trying to figure out what’s going on. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, if I were you, I would simply replace SSDs put any of SSD1 (windows) SSD2(16.04) SSD3(18.04)  and unplug others. Many version of OSs inside one disk or one computer is nothing good to me. https://askubuntu.com/questions/898217/two-different-versions-of-ubuntu-separate-hard-drives-but-single-boot

Comment: I have multiple installs and no issues, other than the last install overwrites /EFI/ubuntu with that install's boot. I now just edit /EFI/ubuntu/grub to be my main working installl. If external drive you must partition in advance and add an ESP - efi system partition as first partition. Then reinstall grub, or copy all of /EFI/Boot & /EFI/ubuntu from internal drive to external drive. Then edit internal drive. Or see this: Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379